# Can't trim image with Paperclip / ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, paperclip, image-manipulation

With Paperclip I download images and crop these to the right dimensions. These images also have white top/bottom borders, or white left/right borders to make them fill a specific resolution. I don't want these white borders so I tried adding the convert option `-trim` and `-trim +repage`..

[image]

One of the ending commands used is this:

`convert '/folder/file.jpg' -auto-orient -resize "x266" -crop "348x266+3+0" +repage -trim +repage 'folder/file'`

But it doesn't remove the white.

Comment: Maybe you should post an image sample.

Comment: Thanks, added an image, hope this makes it more clear..

Comment: You should probably drop the ruby/rails tags and from the title; this is a paperclip question and doesn't have anything to do with ruby/rails (as it turns out, now that you found the answer)

Comment: You're right, updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `jpg` image which needed to be converted had `fuzzy` white borders.. (Not solid white)

What I needed to add was the following:

```
-fuzz 2% -trim +repage
```